# How to implement angular nested ng-repeat with groupBy filter and ng-model binding on input

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a nested `ng-repeat` loop. It uses the `groupBy` and `toArray` filters from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

The issue is that I have an editable input field in the nested array. Without implementing "track by" on the ng-repeats every time the value changes when typed it looses focus [as described in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392906/ng-repeat-on-object-properties-but-defocuses-input-box-after-typing).

If I try to put a `track by` on the repeats it breaks and shows many fields with blank values. Is there any way to correctly implement `track by` in this situation so that the repeats display correctly and I can type into the input field without it losing focus?

Here is example, if you run it you will see as soon as you edit input you loose focus:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

  this.Parts = [{
    Id: 1,
    ShortDescription: "Premium Shocks",
    SupplierSku: "ZXU3322",
    SellPrice: 110,
    SellPriceInclGst: 130,
    ProfitExclGst: 10,
    SupplierName: 'Super Sports',
    Quantity: 3
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    ShortDescription: "Spanner",
    SupplierSku: "4444",
    SellPrice: 44,
    SellPriceInclGst: 130,
    ProfitExclGst: 10,
    SupplierName: 'Bobs Parts',
    Quantity: 1
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    ShortDescription: "Spark Plugs",
    SupplierSku: "xxxxx",
    SellPrice: 10,
    SellPriceInclGst: 130,
    ProfitExclGst: 10,
    SupplierName: 'Bobs Parts',
    Quantity: 5
  }]


});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">

  <table class="table" ng-controller='MainCtrl as main'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Short Descriptin</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Total + GST</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="supplier in main.Parts | groupBy:'SupplierName' | toArray:true | orderBy:'$key'">

      <tr class="title-display-row">
        <td colspan="6">{{ supplier.$key }}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="item in supplier track by $index">
        <td>{{ item.ShortDescription }} {{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.SupplierSku }}</td>

        <td class="field-cell">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="text" name="quantity[$index]" ng-model="item.Quantity" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.SellPrice | currency }}</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Total-gst</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you create a fiddle please. Your question is clear but it will give a better idea to the exact problem

Comment: @Pratik I've added a code snippet.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the unlikely event someone has the same problem as this... the solution was to remove the `toArray|true` filter.

Then instead of accessing the supplier name with `{{ supplier.$key }}` I'm using `{{ Supplier[0].SupplierName }}`. Because each `supplier` in the loop is an array of items with the same supplier name so I can just take the first and use it.

Comment: (for what it's worth) this didn't solve my problem, but your example did show me how to use angular.filter correctly.  Keep doing that!!